# Does commit-interval change improve batch performance?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring batch described as like below,
I I change commit-interval from 1 to 10000, will this change improve the performance?

```
    <batch:job id="weeklyPartnerPointAddJob" restartable="true">
        <batch:step id="weeklyPartnerPointAddStep" parent="noTransactionStep">
            <batch:tasklet task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" throttle-limit="1">
                <batch:chunk reader="selectPartnerListForPointReader" processor="weeklyPartnerPointAccumulateItemProcessor" commit-interval="1" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
```

- The `weeklyPartnerPointAccumulateItemProcessor` processor manipulate the read input and update the record inside the processor. so I didn't create a ItemWriter for update logic.
- The `noTransactionStep` described like following, which doesn't maintain transaction.

```
  <bean id="noTransactionStep" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.factory.SimpleStepFactoryBean" abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="resourcelessTransactionManager" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="startLimit" value="10" />
    <property name="commitInterval" value="3" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: Why not just test it? If you can't, now would be a good time to invest in making that possible. [See also](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the commit-interval may impact the performance. There is no best value, it depends on the context. Determining the "best" value **for your specific use case** is an empirical process, ie you need to try different values and find the one that leads to best performance.

A commit-interval of 1 is too small and will lead to a large number of transactions (equal to the number of input items). This could degrade the performance significantly. A value of 10.000 can lead to long running transactions and probably high memory usage (depending on the use case) which can also degrade the performance. In my experience, a value of 100 or 1000 is a good start.